# Django React - cannot load static files from static folder

Tags: reactjs, django, deployment, static

I am trying to deploy Django-React app, but If I try to connect on the 127.0.0.1:8000 it loads only title tag and then the page is blank. In console I can see it cannot load `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/main.4f7faf6a.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` and all the other files and I have no idea why.
Folder structure:

```
backend:
   app
frontend
```

Relevant code from settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')
]
```

in TEMPLATES I have:

```
'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')
    ],
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

First I build the `npm run build` and copy the build into backend folder. Then I run `python manage.py collectstatic` and `runserver`. It loads only title tag and blank page.. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. I had wrong path to the static folder.
I changed:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')
]
```

to this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]
```